# 1) When can a time coordinate be separated in the interval (General relativity) ? 2) Unclear proper time expression

Tags: general-relativity

1. One has that $ds^{2} = g_{ij}(x)dx^{i}dx^{j}$. I often see that the interval is re-expressed with a time "seperation" of the form:
   $$ 
   ds^{2} = g_{00}(x)dt^{2} + \tilde{g}_{ab}dx^{a}dx^{b} \;\; a,b = 1,2,3
   $$
   When can this be done?
2. Why can the proper time infinitesimal always be written in the form (*according to Wiki "Proper time"*):
   $
   d\tau = \sqrt{g_{00}(x)}dt \; ?
   $

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: For the first one, it's when the 'cross terms' $g_{0a}$ (and correspondingly, $g_{a0}$) are zero

Comment: Can you always find coordinates such that these cross terms are zero?

Comment: Does [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/272957/what-do-the-off-diagonal-elements-of-the-metric-tensor-represent) help?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)**

I believe this can be done always, but I am not sure. You need to get rid of the cross terms $g_{0a}$ and you have 4 coordinate transformations at your disposal to get rid of the 3 metric functions, while keeping $g_{00}$ positive (assuming the signature is (+,-,-,-)). This looks like a problem that has a solution.

**2)**

It cannot. The proper time is always attached to some worldline. For any worldline whatsoever, the general formula is:
$$d\tau=c^{-1}ds=c^{-1}\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu}$$
This reduces to your formula only along worldlines that keep $x^1$,$x^2$ and $x^3$ constant.

Comment: For (1), what about a non-static spacetime, e.g. the Kerr spacetime?

Comment: @NiharKarve interesting question. The thing is, in Kerr spacetime it is the timelike killing vector that is not hypersurface orthogonal. But we are not assuming $t$ being given by this vector.

Comment: @Umaxo Thanks! Sorry to ask again but if you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time#In_general_relativity under general relativity they say that "In the same way that coordinates can be chosen such that x1, x2, x3 = const in special relativity, this can be done in general relativity too." Is this not always the case?

Comment: @ThomasHasler I see. You can find such coordinates for any worldline P along which you integrate, that is true. I just assumed you look for global coordinates in which the formula is true for any worldline.